# How to get the training accuracy in Scikit-learn RandomForest?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am following this tutorials: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/random-forests-classifier-python on using Scikit-learn with random forests. However, the current code only shows the test accuracy whereas I want to know the training accuracy as well since may dataset is very small.

The code to get the test accuracy is:

```py
from sklearn import metrics
print("Accuracy:", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

How would I modify this to get the training accuracy?

Comment: You can get the training set predictions as `y_train_pred = clf.predict(X_train)` where `clf` is your fitted `RandomForestClassifier `. After that you can use `metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, y_train_pred)` to get the training accuracy. Alternatively, you can use `clf.score(X_train, y_train)`, which should give you the same result.

Comment: That works, please convert to an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the training set predictions as

```py
y_train_pred = clf.predict(X_train)
```

where `clf` is your fitted `RandomForestClassifier`. After that you can use

```py
metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, y_train_pred)
```

to calculate the training accuracy. Alternatively, you can use

```py
clf.score(X_train, y_train)
```

which should give you the same result.